# Programmatically save changes of an editable uitable

Tags: matlab, user-interface, callback, matlab-uitable

I created an UItable in Matlab which I fill with various values and options.
It looks like:

[image]

the corresponding code is the following:

```
selector_1 = { 'A'; 'B' ; 'C' };
selector_2 = { 'A.1'; 'A.2'; 'A.3'; ...
               'B.1'; 'B.2'; 'B.3'; ...
               'C.1'; 'C.2'; 'C.3' };

rows = 5;           

f = figure('name','Configuration of output','Position',[200 200 430 25+rows*20],'numbertitle','off','MenuBar','none');

dat =  {'select outputfile...', 'select identifier...', 'Specifier',  'Index'};
dat = repmat(dat,rows,1);
columnname =   {'Output file                   ',...
                'Identifier                    ',...
                'Specifier          ', 'Index'};
columnformat = { {selector_1{:}}, {selector_2{:}}, 'char', 'numeric' };
columneditable =  [true true true true]; 
t = uitable('Units','normalized','Position',...
            [0 0 1 1], 'Data', dat,... 
            'ColumnName', columnname,...
            'ColumnFormat', columnformat,...
            'ColumnEditable', columneditable,...
            'RowName',[]);
set(t, 'Data', dat,'celleditcallback','get(t,''Data'')');
```

So I run the code and the figure is open. The underlying script has therefore finished.
When I now edit the table my uitable object is changed and after I finished I can get my final configuration with:

```
finalconfig =  get(t,'Data');
```

But the thing is I need manually type this line, because my script has already finished. If I put this line at the end of my script, I get an error.

So I thought about using the following loop, to detect when I close the table and to store the last configuration

```
while ~isempty(findobj('name','Configuration of output'))
    % some action
end
finalconfig =  get(t,'Data');
```

And I tried everything to put inside the loop, the whole script, just the `set` command including the `celleditcallback`, and other things, but nothing worked. Either my script get stucked inside the loop or the display of my table is not updated when I edit a value. I also tried `drawnow` at different positions. How one handles this situation? How can I automatically store my final results?
I assume "closing the window" is the best action to detect, as I don't think I could implement a "save" button. I also tried to create a gui using `GUIDE` but got completely lost, I hope to solve it without.

---

Edit:
I was now able to implement a "save"-button and tried the callback as follows:

```
uimenu('Label','Save configuration','Callback',@saveConfig);
function saveConfig(~,~)
        output = get(t,'Data',);
        save([pwd 'output.mat'],'output');
end
```

also I implemented a custom `CloseRequestFcn` as suggested by Lucius Domitius Ahenobarbus. But then I have either one of the following problems:

**1)**
I define everything as a script, everything works fine, but I need to define functions like `@saveConfig` (actually my favorite) or `@my_Closefcn` as a unique function-file in my workspace and I have a hard time to pass the right parameters as `dat` always remains the same, even though it actually gets changend.
(The [example from the mathworks site](http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/matlab/creating_plots/the-figure-close-request-function.html) works! But it doesn't need additional parameters.)

**2)** When I use

```
function configuration
% my script from above
end
```

I can implement `@saveConfig` or `@my_Closefcn` directly (nested) and I guess the passing of the parameters would work fine. But the editing of my table does not work anymore, throwing the following error:

> Error using handle.handle/get
>
> Invalid or deleted object.
>
> Error while evaluating uitable CellEditCallback

How to solve that?
Now that I know that I can even add buttons to an uitable I REALLY like to avoid `GUIDE`.
My code above is executable, so I'd be glad if you try it to see what my actual problem is, as it is hard to describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depending on using GUIDE or not:

use the CloseRequestFcn->

without GUIDE use:

```
%write your own CloseRequestFcn and set the figure CloseRequest-Callback to it:
set(gcf,'CloseRequestFcn',@my_closefcn)
%use gcf or the handle of the figure directly
```

and define my_closefcn including a delete statement for the figure-handle, else the figure will not close :)

See the docs for more information about "Redefining the CloseRequestFcn".

with GUIDE:

you can edit the CloseRequestFcn by inspecting the figure. There is a field called CloseRequestFcn that will create the function automatically and you dont need to take care about getting the handle. It will look like this:

```
function figure1_CloseRequestFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to figure1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Hint: delete(hObject) closes the figure
delete(hObject);
```

Now BEFORE deleting the figure, you should be able to get the data of the uitable (if you have the handle) and I would suggest to just assign the data to the base workspace, like:

```
assignin('base', 'finalTableData', get(myTableHandle,'Data'));
```

**EDIT**

as I was not clear enough, see this example:

(use within one single script)->

```
function test
h=figure;
x=1:10;
mytable=uitable(h,'Data',x);
set(h,'CloseRequestFcn',@myCloseFcn)
%give a unique Tag:
set(h,'Tag', 'myTag')
set(mytable,'Tag','myTableTag')
end

function myCloseFcn(~,~)
myfigure=findobj('Tag','myTag');
myData=get(findobj(myfigure,'Tag','myTableTag'),'Data')
assignin('base','myTestData',myData)
delete(myfigure)
end
```

in fact, there is no need to take care for the parameters of your Closereq-Callback, if you know how to find the handle of the figure! Just give something to your figure/uitable that you are able to identify it later on. I used 'Tag', because the first thing I would think of, but there would be other parameters as well.

Comment: I cannot make it work, please have a look at my edited question. I think it is good approach, though I'd prefer the "save" button. Both approaches still have the same difficulties.

Comment: now it's even working for my example. The only difference between your example and mine was that I used `set(t, 'Data', dat,'celleditcallback','get(t,''Data'')');` as it seemed absolutely necessary for me. But it is obviously useless and jsut makes trouble. Thanks a lot! I hope now to be able implement your function in the save button, but it should be the same.

Comment: and another short little question: in your example how could I get the variable `x` of your fist function, but in the second function? It's neither part of my figure, nor of my table. And I don't know how to access the function workspace.

Comment: for this, I suggest to use the guidata-property of the figure. just put it into the struct UserData and it will be there later on, if you save it correctly. e.g. within the closereq-fcn it would look like: get(myfigure,'UserData');

Answer (score 0):

There are only two differences I can think of between running the code directly after the code, or inside the code.

**1. Scope**

Perhaps you are actually working with functions, rather than scripts. In this case the problem may be that inside your function, something you need is out of scope.

**2. Timing**

Though it is rare, sometimes the computer may seem to be finished, whilst it is actually still busy (for a few milliseconds or so).

---

Here are the steps to a general approach:

1. Make sure there is a trivial line at the place where you want to insert your command (`1==1` for example)
2. Put a breakpoint at the line
3. Once matlab stops at the breakpoint, wait a second and try to run your command.

If it works I would bet on problem number 2. try placing a `pause(1)` before your command and see whether it helps.

If it doesn't work you are likely meeting problem number 1. Now it becomes a matter of finding the right place to put your command. And if the command cannot be put somewhere else in the code, perhaps try an ugly `evalin(,'base')`. However, the latter should really be considered a workaround rather than a solution.